# Is there a way to seed hashes using the Faker gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, faker

I am trying to seed some data but I have a field that takes in a hash. When I do the following

```
50.times do 
  Event.create(
    name: Faker::Internet.name,
    data: Faker::Lorem.words(4),
    uri:  Faker::Internet.url
    )
end
events = Event.all
```

I get an error saying that data is being seeded as an array since it's a hash field. Is there a work around this?

```
rake aborted!
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidValue: 
Problem:
  Value of type Array cannot be written to a field of type Hash
Summary:
  Tried to set a value of type Array to a field of type Hash
```

I tried doing the following:

```
data: Faker::Lorem.words(4).to_h
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What kind of data would you expect the hash to contain?  Are the number of key-value pairs fixed, random, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
Event.create(
  name: Faker::Internet.name,
  data: Hash[*Faker::Lorem.words(4)],
  uri:  Faker::Internet.url
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Faker::Crypto.sha256`](https://rubydoc.info/github/faker-ruby/faker/master/Faker%2FCrypto.sha256).

Example:

```
> Faker::Crypto.sha256
=> "ee25a4b399dd3c748d310aedd458f0662d4736f470d2c8342553e1e8998b4bc2"
```